# Is it possible to have a class member variable as a variable in a different class?

Tags: class, pointers, arduino, arduino-c++

First time here, up until now I have managed to solve my problems with google, but not this time...

As part of an Arduino project I require a menu object (a class member) to display (and edit) a variable taken from a parameter object (a different class member). Currently I can use the the parameter object variable in the initialization of the menu object and it displays. However if I edit the menu object it is not reflected in the parameter object - I am assuming the code just copies the object in memory when I initialize it - makes sense. I have tried with pointers but I lack understanding and the same thing seems to happen.

Here's some simplified code - note currently I am using public variables and no constructor for simplicity, this will probably change

```cxx
class Parameter {
  public:
    const char* plabel; 
    uint16_t value;
};

class SubMenu {
  public:
    const char* mlabel;
    uint16_t valueShown;
};

Parameter parameter[] {
  {"Para 1", 123},
  {"Para 2", 456}
};

Parameter *parameterP[] {parameter};

SubMenu mainMenu[] {
  {"Menu item 1", parameterP[0]->value},
  {"Menu item 2", parameterP[1]->value}
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(mainMenu[0].valueShown);
  mainMenu[0].valueShown++;
  Serial.println(mainMenu[0].valueShown);
  Serial.println(parameterP[0]->value);
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

As you can imagine the serial output is:

```
123
124
123
```

If someone could help me make this code work as desired (I guess using pointers?) that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your "simplified" code is probably too simplified. The definition `Parameter *parameterP[] {parameter};` is equivalent to `Parameter *parameterP[1] {parameter};`, which means `parameterP[1]` is out of bounds. However `parameterP[0][1]` is valid.

Comment: you probably want a callback mechanism instead of a loop. I am not an expert in Arduino, but you have a read at the observer pattern

Comment: As for your problem, what you might want might be *references*, or possibly pointers to the value. (i.e. `SubMenu::valueShown` should be either `uint16_t&` or `uint16_t*` instead).